# Where to use flush and _flush/synced commands

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand that _flush/synced can be used while doing rolling restart. I am not sure where flush can be used. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flush doesn't guarantee the data is written to disk in case of asyn mode. flush/synced will write the data to the disk even in case of asyn mode. So, use flush/synced when you want to sync the data to disk.

Answer (score 1):

flush causes a Lucene commit to happen.

link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-flush.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush.html

Comment: Is there a real time scenario where a devops engineer can execute flush on elasticsearch?

Comment: devops enginner can fire query like this POST twitter/_flush

Comment: I am rephrasing my question. In what kind of situation you will flush the data  from memory to disk?